# How to get rows with max(of a column) when using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

When I tried:

```
select * 
from some_table 
group by table_id 
order by timestamp desc;
```

I am gettings rows which have least `timestamp` values for that particular `table_id`(which I use for grouping)

How can I get the rows which have highest `timestamp` values for that particular `table_id`.

I also tried:

```
select * 
from some_table 
group by table_id 
having max(timestamp) 
order by timestamp desc;
```

which gives the same result as in the 1st case.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from your_table t
inner join 
(
   select table_id, max(created_timestamp) as mts
   from your_table
   group by table_id 
) x on x.table_id = t.table_id 
    and x.mts = t.created_timestamp
```

In MySQL you can do

```
select *, max(created_timestamp) as mts
from your_table
group by table_id
```

but that will not make sure you get the corresponding data to your `max(created_timestamp)` but only to your `table_id`

Comment: I saw few solution like the 1 you suggested. But the reason I didn't want to go with that is, The query in my question is part of a main query which already has lot of joins. I was expecting a simple(faster) solution to get the latest row instead of oldest(which is the default) when using group by. Is this the only solution?

Comment: What columns do you really need from your_table?

Comment: I want the complete row(all columns).

Comment: That gives the max of `created_timestamp` but the remaining values in the row will be that of the oldest.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in my answer. You have to use a subquery to get the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY timestamp) t1 GROUP BY t1.id
```